# How to disable scrolling of AppBarLayout in CoordinatorLayout?

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, supportmapfragment, android-appbarlayout

I have `MapFragment` with parallax effect inside `AppBarLayout`:

[image]

I want to disable scrolling on `AppBarLayout`, because it is not possible to move across map, since touch evenys on the map are always handled as scroll events. 
I would like to handle collapsing of `AppBarLayout` by scrolling `RecyclerView` only, which is on the bottom of the screen.

This is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="@color/white"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap"
        app:titleEnabled="false">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/map"
                android:name="com.androidmapsextensions.SupportMapFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="73dp"
            app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/search_bar"
                layout="@layout/layout_searchbar" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_shadow"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="3dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/search_bar"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@drawable/toolbar_dropshadow"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/farm_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

Thank you for the response.

Comment: Where is your `CoordinatorLayout`?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

I'm not sure I got it, but I think you are looking for a `DragCallback`.

The `DragCallback` interface allows to choose whether the sibling scrolling view should be controlled by scrolls onto the `AppBarLayout`.

You can define one by calling:

```
CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) appBarLayout.getLayoutParams();
AppBarLayout.Behavior behavior = (AppBarLayout.Behavior) params.getBehavior();
behavior.setDragCallback(new AppBarLayout.Behavior.DragCallback() {
    @Override
    public boolean canDrag(@NonNull AppBarLayout appBarLayout) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

By always returning `false`, your scrolling view will not be controlled by the ABL any longer.

**Note:** before calling this you should check that `ViewCompat.isLaidOut(appBarLayout)`, otherwise `params.getBehavior()` will return null.

Comment: Actually the solution I added above did the trick, but thank you for help anyway. I'm curious so I will give it a try :)

Comment: Setting onInterceptTouchEvent to the coordinator might give you some problem in the future. This is the "official" solution (if I got your question).

Comment: Can't make it work with this solution. Can you explain a little bit more, please? Thanks

Comment: @joaquin if canDrag returns true, you can scroll the whole view by scrolling the appbarlayout. If canDrag returns false, the appbarlayout does not react to scroll events.

Comment: The "behavior" variable that is returned to me is null. How did you get it to work?

Comment: i got null while accessing params.getBehavior. This answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/33230473/6117565) is another way to change behavior and it worked for me:

Comment: don't forget about the ''Note"

Answer (score 40):

**Problem**

1. AppBarLayout scrolls even if the scroll content fits the screen.
2. It is because by default we can drag AppBarLayout by touching & dragging AppBarLayout.

**Solution**

1. We will disable "Dragging" behaviour for AppBarLayout.

   ```
   // Disable "Drag" for AppBarLayout (i.e. User can't scroll appBarLayout by directly touching appBarLayout - User can only scroll appBarLayout by only using scrollContent)
   if (appBarLayout.getLayoutParams() != null) {
       CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) appBarLayout.getLayoutParams();
       AppBarLayout.Behavior appBarLayoutBehaviour = new AppBarLayout.Behavior();
       appBarLayoutBehaviour.setDragCallback(new AppBarLayout.Behavior.DragCallback() {
           @Override
           public boolean canDrag(@NonNull AppBarLayout appBarLayout) {
               return false;
           }
       });
       layoutParams.setBehavior(appBarLayoutBehaviour);
   }
   ```

**Reference**

1. This is just extension of  "natario's" accepted answer above.
2. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.Behavior.DragCallback.html

Comment: Hi Vasanth! I want to disable user scroll (of CoordinatorLayout) when he scrolls into the recyclerview. how can I do that please?

Answer (score 31):

You can accomplish this by defining a custom `app:layout_behavior` in xml. With this approach you don't have to worry about getting a reference to the `LayoutParams` and doing null checks.

```
  <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
      android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      app:layout_behavior="com.yourcompany.FixedAppBarLayoutBehavior"
      >
```

Then create a custom class that extends from `AppBarLayout.Behavior`.

```
public class FixedAppBarLayoutBehavior extends AppBarLayout.Behavior {

  public FixedAppBarLayoutBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    setDragCallback(new DragCallback() {
      @Override public boolean canDrag(@NonNull AppBarLayout appBarLayout) {
        return false;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Updated with Kotlin version:

```
class FixedAppBarLayoutBehavior(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : AppBarLayout.Behavior(context, attrs) {
  init {
    setDragCallback(object : DragCallback() {
      override fun canDrag(appBarLayout: AppBarLayout): Boolean = false
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

So after two hours of trying I have found a solution, which is pretty simple. I just needed to extend `CoordinatorLayout` and override `OnInterceptTouchEvent` method so the class looks like this:

```
public class NonTouchableCoordinatorLayout extends CoordinatorLayout {
public NonTouchableCoordinatorLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    return false;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

you can use the  `NestedScrollView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false)` to disable the AppBarLayout nestScroll envent

Comment: you can still scroll/expand appbar by dragging your finger on the appbar area.