# Toolbar scroll after setNestedScrollEnabled(false)

Tags: android, scroll, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

I have problem with scrolling toolbar on fragments. In **activity_main.xml** I past fragment (NestedScrollView or RecyclerView) in FrameLayout. On the fragment with RecyclerView scrolling blocked by mRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled (false). But the toolbar continues to move up / down. If before this click on FrameLayout (with fragment_profile.xml), the toolbar is blocked (as it should be).

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

   <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
      app:title=" "
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimary"
      android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
      app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">

    <ImageView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_image_height"
       android:src="@drawable/header_background"
       android:scaleType="fitXY"
       app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
       android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>

   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
       android:id="@+id/toolbar"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
       app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
       android:clipToPadding="true"/>

               <com.sloydev.collapsingavatartoolbar.CollapsingAvatarToolbar
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:collapsedImageSize="32dp"
                    app:expandedImageSize="@dimen/nav_photo_size"
                    app:expandedTextSize="@dimen/toolbar_expanded_text_size"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

                    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/avatar"
                        android:id="@+id/cat_avatar"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/view_padding"
                        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/cat_title"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="@string/roboto.regular"
                        android:textColor="@color/title_color"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/view_padding"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/view_padding"
                        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>

                </com.sloydev.collapsingavatartoolbar.CollapsingAvatarToolbar>

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**fragment_profile.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

**fragment_contacts.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/contacts_recyclerview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

**ContactsFragment.java**

```
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.contacts_recyclerview);
    mRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
    appBar.setExpanded(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve problem, added in AppBarLayout.Behavior DragCallback with return false; 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34112103/5886355