# How to disable scrolling of AppBarLayout when scroll doesnot needed

Tags: android, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

This is my layout file.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/home_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
            app:titleTextColor="@color/colorWhite" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/home_tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorWhite"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="@dimen/tabIndicatorHeight"
            app:tabMinWidth="@dimen/tabMinWidth"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorWhite"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/colorWhite80" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/home_view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

In `CoordinatorLayout`, there are 2 childs. One is `AppBarLayout` and another one is `ViewPager`. When I don't have so much thing to show in the `ViewPager` at that time also `AppBarLayout` is scrolling. I want to stop that scrolling. How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Doesn't [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34108501/how-to-disable-scrolling-of-appbarlayout-in-coordinatorlayout) help you?

Comment: @azizbekian I have updated my question. Above link does not help me to solve this problem. I have already checked that before.