# How to collapse and disable the collapsing tool bar layout programatically in android

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52700455/10045201)! show me how to disable the collapsing tool bar layout. The behavior I want is to collapse and disable the collapsing tool bar and show the error view when there is no internet connection. 
So How can I do the trick , collapsing and disabling the collapsing tool bar layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/40267244/10045201

```java
public void disableAppBar(AppBarLayout appBarLayout) {
    if (appBarLayout.getLayoutParams() != null) {
        CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams)appBarLayout.getLayoutParams();
        AppBarLayout.Behavior appBarLayoutBehaviour = new AppBarLayout.Behavior();
        appBarLayoutBehaviour.setDragCallback(new AppBarLayout.Behavior.DragCallback() {
            @Override
            public boolean canDrag(@NonNull AppBarLayout appBarLayout) {
                return false;
            }
        });
        layoutParams.setBehavior(appBarLayoutBehaviour);
    }
}
```