# Disable CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

my application provide different contents, some of them is with image and others not.
For those which have image i am using CollapsingToolbarLayout it works fine but for those which have not image I want collapse CollapsingToolbarLayout and prevent expanding, disable it.

Here is my item activity code:

```
public class ItemActivity extends BaseActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_item);

        collapsingToolbar = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
        collapsingToolbar.setStatusBarScrimResource(R.color.black_transparent_190);
        collapsingToolbar.setContentScrimResource(R.color.gray_transparent_150);
        collapsingToolbar.setExpandedTitleTextAppearance(R.style.MyTheme_Toolbar_Title_Expanded);

        appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.appbar);
        appBarLayout.setExpanded(false);
        loadData();
    }

    public void loadData() {
        if(haveImage) {
          // loading data and image
          appBarLayout.setExpanded(true, true);
        } else {
          appBarLayout.setExpanded(false);
        }
    }
}
```

I have already tried

```
AppBarLayout.LayoutParams params = (AppBarLayout.LayoutParams) collapsingToolbar.getLayoutParams();
params.setScrollFlags(AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_SCROLL | AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_EXIT_UNTIL_COLLAPSED);
collapsingToolbar.setLayoutParams(params);
```

and

```
CollapsingToolbarLayout.LayoutParams mParams = new CollapsingToolbarLayout.LayoutParams(collapsingToolbar.getLayoutParams());
mParams.setCollapseMode(CollapsingToolbarLayout.LayoutParams.COLLAPSE_MODE_OFF);
mToolbar.setLayoutParams(mParams);
```

It works, it's prevent collapsing!
**But collapsing toolbar is expanded!**

How can I collapse toolbar and disable it for scrolling events?

Comment: I think you should create a simple layout with Linear or Relative for those who does not have image. Check it before setting ContentView.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33193223/using-appbarlayout-behavior-dragcallback-to-control-scroll-of-collapsing-toolbar/33230473#33230473

Answer (score 0):

You use setExpanded(false) on appBarLayout as normal, but you need to create a custom CollapsingToolbarLayout as below

I followed the idea in this [link](http://codetheory.in/android-listview-scrolling-viewgroup-hide-disable-scrollbars/).

Override CollapsingToolbarLayout and override dispatchTouchEvent returning true like this

```
public class MyCustomCollapsingToolbarLayout extends CollapsingToolbarLayout {

    public MyCustomCollapsingToolbarLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return true;
    }
}
```